# Ubuntu 22.04 R6S can't play

Tags: 22.04, games, steam

For some reason when I enter in Rainbow Six Siege (from Steam) and try to start a match it says: [The BattlEye service is not running. Please try again after restarting the game.] but every time I reopen it says the same thing, any tips?

Comment: Rainbox Six does not support Linux: https://www.protondb.com/app/359550